# Facebook login: able to get more data using Accounts framework

Tags: ios, facebook, permissions, acaccountstore, fbsdkloginkit

In a small test project I implemented a Facebook login feature using both iOS' built in [Accounts framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountStoreClassRef/index.html) and Facebook's official [FBSDKLoginKit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios).

I noticed however that when a user logs in using the native permissions dialog, I get access to more data compared to Facebook's login SDK. I'm able to access birthday and current city:

[image: screenshot of Facebook permissions]

It's odd, [Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_birthday) states your app should go trough Facebook's Login Review if your app requests access to a user's exact birthday.

Should I be in any way worried to access that information using Apple's Accounts framework? (as it is clearly bypassing something Facebook put in place to protect users). Should this be reported to Apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permission work without review for everyone with a role in the App, else you would not be able to test your App before sending it in for review. More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: So every iOS app that uses the built in Accounts framework is supposed to go trough Facebook's Login Review then? (as it gives access to the birthday of a user)

Comment: what "accounts framework" are you talking about? you do need to go through login review for the user_birthday permission if you want to go public, of course.

Comment: Apple's framework to access accounts configured in the settings (Facebook, Twitter, ...). [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/AccountsFrameworkRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011024)

Comment: alright. either way, the procedure is platform-independent. check out the link in my answer, it covers everything you need to know about login review.